# Best practices for tagging a ECS task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

We can add tags to EC2 instances to help us better track billing usages and to manage instances.

Is there a way to achieve when deploying containers in ECS? I would like the running container to have the ability to know what tag it currently have attached.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you're ultimately trying to visualize after the fact. I'll share a few off-the-cuff thoughts below, and maybe you can extrapolate on these to build something that satisfies your needs.

---

As you probably are aware, ECS Tasks themselves don't support the notion of tags, however there are some workarounds that you could consider. For example, depending on how you're logging your application's behavior (eg. batching logs to CloudWatch Logs), you could create a Log Stream name, for each ECS Task, that contains a delimited array of tags.

As part of a POC I was building recently, I used the auto-generated computer name to dynamically create CloudWatch Log Stream names. You could easily append or prepend the tag data that you embed in your container images, and then query the tag information from the CloudWatch Log Streams later on.

---

Another option would be to simply log a metric to CloudWatch Metrics, based on the number of ECS Tasks running off of each unique Task Definition in ECR.

You could build a very simple Lambda function that queries your ECS Tasks, on each cluster, and writes the Task count, for each unique Task Definition, to CloudWatch Metrics on a per-minute basis. CloudWatch Event Rules allow you to trigger Lambda functions on a cron schedule, so you can customize the period to your liking.

You can use this metric data to help drive scaling decisions about the ECS Cluster, the Services and Tasks running on it, and the underlying EC2 compute instances that support the ECS Cluster.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Trevor it is helpful. I am trying to allow users to tag ECS tasks in a way the running container can programmatically query its own "Tag"s. I guess passing in Environment variables is a way to achieve this but I find the Environment variable approach is not as user friendly as I would like it to be. :) 

Thanks for the information Trevor! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this while trying to work out the current situation. For future searchers: I believe [tagging was added](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate-now-allow-resources-tagging-/) some time after this question, in late 2018.

I've not yet worked out if you can set this up in the Console or if it's a feature of the API only, but e.g. the Terraform AWS provider now lets you set service *or* task definition tags to 'bubble through' to tasks – including Fargate ones – via [`propagate_tags`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_service.html#propagate_tags).

I've just enabled this and it works but forces a new ECS service – I guess this is related to it not being obviously editable in the Console UI.